# Are general electric battery questions okay here?

Tags: support

It's quite usual to have general questions on batteries, for example:

> Is it true that all else being equal huge rechargeable batteries like ones used in power tools and electric cars have better lifetime compared to tiny batteries like ones used in cell phones?

Are such questions okay on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this gets messy. The site support questions related to electronic design(even though our name has changed again). However, if the question is from a consumer electronics perspective it will not fair well. This often becomes quickly apparent as when you as a question like:

> Is it true that all else being equal
>   huge rechargeable batteries like ones
>   used in power tools and electric cars
>   have better lifetime compared to tiny
>   batteries like ones used in cell
>   phones?

The first think I can tell you is that it depends on battery chemistry, which does not necessarily correlate with size, but with task, demands and budget. This is actually a very very broad question that does not have a great answer. This I would closed as "Not a real question" as the

> It's difficult to tell what is being
>   asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly
>   broad, or rhetorical and cannot be
>   reasonably answered in its current
>   form.

Question is a bit broad. We could also run into subjectivity as their are different ideas of size and there could quickly be arguments.

If someone asks a concise question about batteries it will stay open 99 times out of 100. The major thing to focus on would be technical problems.

We have had questions such as:

[How do I connect two identical batteries to increase the consumer lifetime?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2675/230)

[Are coin cells a suitable replacement for AA batteries?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5666/230)

[Small batteries for use in cold but not freezing environments.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2790/230)

Comment: I see. The "all else being equal" was there on purpose to mean something like "of two cells with the same chemistry and whatever else will the one with bigger size have better lifetime"?

Comment: @Sharptooth, that would be a valid question to go into. Also, thanks for the question name edit. I thought the same thing but I am working so it is hard to spend time on those things.